# Blender: export error root bone offset while exporting as Ogre mesh

Tags: export, root, blender, ogre

I've recently started working with Blender. I've created a character with bones following different tutorials. But when I try to export it as Ogre mesh I get the error that the root bone has a location and rotation offset.

I've tried many solutions like ctrl+a->location, reset position, setting location and rotation to 0,0,0. But nothing seems to be working. As I couldn't export with animations I tried exporting the model without any movement at all. But I'm still getting the same error. I'm using blender 2.62 (i changed from 2.63 as it was giving erros like faces missing ..). Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem and tried different things in attempt to solve it. When I tried to correct an existing armature, it didn't bring any results. The only thing that worked for me is creating an armature from scratch, starting from a root bone and placing it correctly from the very beginning. Add a single bone, than press alt+G and alt+R to clear location and rotation. Then, adjust the position of the mesh, depending on where you want the your root bone to be. Then, extrude it further to make the entire armature, but don't change its position or location anymore. When done, parent armature to mesh.
I don't know if there are any other solutions, neither if this one is the best, but it worked for me. 
Good luck!